# HTML about line breaks?

Tags: html, css, break, word-wrap

So, I'm creating a website in Dreamweaver (class is all about Dreamweaver) and I am stumped on one last part of the layout for my page.

I currently have a "View Cart" button at the top right of my page, and to the left of it was all white space, so I decided to put a 768x15 ad right there. However, if I put the ad in the same group as the cart, it will also align right, and just to the left of the "View Cart".
If I put the ad above the View Cart, there's a line wrap thus leaving more empty space, and same with after.

My simple question: Is there any way to get the ad and my "View Cart" button on the same line without the ad being aligned to the right hand side of the page?

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd xhtml 1.0 transitional//en" "http://www.w3.org/tr/xhtml1/dtd/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
            <!--
                ez games
                author: kyle meek
                3/24/2013
            -->
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>ez games - home page</title>
        <link href="ez_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="spryassets/sprymenubarhorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="spryassets/sprymenubar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body id="bodyformat">
        <p id="logincart"><a href="viewcart.html">view cart</a></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            google_ad_client = "ca-pub-0707070728226508";
            /* smalltop */
            google_ad_slot = "4701711529";
            google_ad_width = 728;
            google_ad_height = 15;
            //-->
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
        </script>
        <p id="logobanner"><img name="ez_logo" src="" width="280" height="150" alt="ez games logo" style="background-color: #ffda00" />
        <img src="" width="1000" height="150" alt="ez games banner" style="background-color: #4212af" /></p>
        <br />
        <h3 id="textalign"><a href="index.html">home</a> &dagger; <a href="about_us.html">about us</a> &dagger; <a href="games.html">games</a> &dagger; <a href="contact_us.html">contact us</a> &dagger; <a href="locate_us.html">locate us</a></h3>
        
        <div id="ad1" align="center">
            <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                google_ad_client = "ca-pub-0707070728226508";
                /* banner ad */
                google_ad_slot = "9705490722";
                google_ad_width = 468;
                google_ad_height = 60;
                //-->
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
            </script>
        </div>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <span id="vertnav">
            <h2>systems</h2><hr />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="atari.html">atari</a></li>
                <li><a href="sega_genesis.html">sega genesis</a></li>
                <li><a href="ps1.html">playstation</a></li>
                <li><a href="ps2.html">playstation 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="ps3.html">playstation 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="xbox.html">x-box</a></li>
                <li><a href="xbox360.html">x-box 360</a></li>
                <li><a href="nes.html">nes</a></li>
                <li><a href="snes.html">super nes</a></li>
                <li><a href="nintendo64.html">nintendo 64</a></li>
                <li><a href="gamecube.html">gamecube</a></li>
                <li><a href="wii.html">nintendo wii</a></li>
                <li><a href="wiiu.html">nintendo wii-u</a></li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    
        <section id="sect1">
            <aside id="sides"><h1>like us on facebook!</h1><br />
                <p><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.facebook.com/ezgamesofficial"
                        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
                        style="border:none; width:200px; height:80px"></iframe></p>
                <hr />
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    <!--
                    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-0707070728226508";
                    /* smallrect */
                    google_ad_slot = "5399715525";
                    google_ad_width = 180;
                    google_ad_height = 150;
                    //-->
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript"
                    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
                </script>
            </aside>
            <article id="art1"><h1>home</h1>
                <p>greetings! content of article one goes here! paragraphs are here. greetings! content of article one goes here! paragraphs are here. greetings! content of article one goes here! paragraphs are here. greetings! content of article one goes here! paragraphs are here. greetings! content of article one goes here! paragraphs are here. greetings! content of article one goes here! paragraphs are here.</p>
            </article>
            <article id="art2"><h1>article numero dos</h1>
                <p>lorem ipsum article 2 blah blah info. lorem ipsum article 2 blah blah info. lorem ipsum article 2 blah blah info. lorem ipsum article 2 blah blah info. lorem ipsum article 2 blah blah info. lorem ipsum article 2 blah blah info. </p>
            </article>
        </section>
        <footer id="foot"><hr />copyright&copy; ez games 2013 &dagger;&dagger;&dagger; all rights reserved.</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my css

```
#bodyformat #logincart {
    text-align: right;
}
#bodyformat #logincart a {
    color: #4212af;
    background-color: #ffda00;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: We need some code please, and a working example would be great :)

Comment: Yes, there are quite a few ways to accomplish what you'd like, but our answers would be way too vague without at least your HTML. Is the cart button in a container, like a div?

Comment: Your image is kind of helpful, but what really gets things solved fast is if you can reproduce the problem you are having at somewhere like http://www.jsfiddle.net/ . If you can make one there then it will be a lot easier to provide help and get your ad in the right place.

Comment: My apologies, the code is now there. HTML and CSS, sorry it isn't separated by code blocks, just the "And my CSS" :X

Comment: Can't you `float:right` the `#logincart`? Wrap a `div` element over both the ad's `script` tag and the cart. Set the new `div` with css `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a float instead of a text-align.

```
#bodyformat #logincart {
    float: right;
}
```

More info:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Comment: Oh my god. Changing the text-align to float worked. I know HTML and CSS, but sometimes I use wrong variants for formatting and it completely messes me up. I hate getting those EXTREMELY small logical errors. Thank you very much.